# Can a dog be "friendly"?

Tags: adjectives

People sometimes colloquially refer to dogs as *friendly*. Is that an imprecise use of language? Does being friendly not require the subject that quality is ascribed to to possess a model of at least one other subject's internal state and to consciously take actions to positively affect that state? I think a dog can be pleasant, which does not require any conscious effort on the dog's part, but friendly?

Comment: But *friendly* **can** mean pleasant. It can also mean not hostile, among other things. What seems to be the problem here? A friendly dog could just be the opposite of a hostile dog.

Comment: @tchrist, the problem is that I am wondering whether that is imprecise use of language. My intuition is that pleasant does not require conscious effort, while friendly does.

Comment: not sure why people feel the need to downvote and migrate this to an English Language Learner SE thereby implying I have no command of the English language. I believe there is a legitimate question here about precise semantics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there’s nothing at all wrong with talking about friendly dogs. You’re over-thinking this.

The OED has citations dating back to the 1600s of *friendly shade* and *friendly colours*, and going back to Chaucer in the 1300s we see *friendly aspects* of planets back in the 1300s.

Even places can be friendly, but since a dog is a creature, you don’t even have to go that far. It falls under the sense of being on good, amicable, or affectionate terms.